# How to handle multiple redirection using Guzzle, Goutte and Symfony 3?

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte, guzzle6, symfony-3.2

I want to crawl https://www.socialbakers.com/ but I am having trouble handling the multiple redirections when doing a post in logging in to the site. First redirect is to a HTML page with JavaScript doing the redirection.

I want to trace all the redirection request URL and if it is possible to do post/get request to each URL.

Answer (score 1):

Goutte is a **simple** web scraper, because it doesn't support JS.

If you are stuck with JS, then you need something more powerful, like Selenium or PhantomJS.

Take a look at PhantomJS, it's simple and fast.

Selenium also has a driver for PhantomJS, if you prefer to stay with PHP (you can use [Mink](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink) with Selenium and PhantomJS).